What is the meaning of Javascript Curly braces around mulitple variables
What is the meaning of Javascript Curly braces around mulitple variables? For example, what is { setRows, setRowModesModel } in toolbar: { setRows, setRowModesModel }? Is it an object?
<DataGrid
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    editMode="row"
    rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
    onRowModesModelChange={handleRowModesModelChange}
    onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
    processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
    slots={{ toolbar: EditToolbar }}
    slotProps={{
      toolbar: { setRows, setRowModesModel },
    }}
  />


@blurfus True, but the part of the code that the OP was actually asking about is JavaScript

@Bergi not sure I understood your comment: are you saying that, because it's a parameter passed as JSON object, it's also JavaScript?

@blurfus No JSON anywhere. But yes, { toolbar: { setRows, setRowModesModel }, } is simply a normal JavaScript expression. That it's embedded in some JSX doesn't really matter for the core of the question.

@Bergi gotcha... I see
